# How to show that $Q=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$S$ is a skem-hermitian matrix. How to show that $Q=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$ is unitary?

$$
((I-S)^{-1}(I+S))^*((I-S)^{-1}(I+S))=(I+S)^*((I-S)^{-1})^*(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)
$$
How to reach the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
((I-S)^{-1})^*(I-S)^{-1}&=((I-S)^*)^{-1}(I-S)^{-1}
\\
&=((I-S)(I-S)^*)^{-1}
\\
&=((I-S)(I+S))^{-1}
\\
&=((I+S)(I-S))^{-1}
\\&=(I-S)^{-1} (I+S)^{-1}
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
(I+S)^*((I-S)^{-1})^*(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)&=(I-S)(I-S)^{-1} (I+S)^{-1}(I+S)=I
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use $(I + S)^{*} = I^{*} + S^{*} = I - S$ and $\left( (I - S)^{-1} \right)^{*} = \left( (I - S)^{*} \right)^{-1}$.